# PrimeFaces tree selection is null

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 2.2.1 Tree component on Glassfish 3.1

I am trying to set the selected node on the Tree to a TreeNode object in my backing bean, but it is always null.

I asked for support on the PrimeFaces forum, but unfortunately received no reply.

```
<p:tree id="contextTree" value="#{contextTreeBean.contextRoot}" var="node" selectionMode="single" selection="#{contextTreeBean.selectedNode}">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node.name}"/>
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
    <h:outputText id="output" value="#{contextTreeBean.output}"/>
    <p:commandButton id ="createButton" value="+" actionListener="#{contextTreeBean.createContext()}" update="contextTree, output"/>


@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class contextTreeBean {

    @EJB
    private ContextFacadeLocal contextFacade;
    private Context context = new Context();
    private TreeNode contextRoot;
    private TreeNode selectedNode;
    private String output;

    /** Creates a new instance of contextTreeBean */
    public contextTreeBean() {
    }

    public void createContext() {
        output = selectedNode.getData().toString();
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public void setOutput(String output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
        return selectedNode;
    }

    public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ContextFacadeLocal getContextFacade() {
        return contextFacade;
    }

    public void setContextFacade(ContextFacadeLocal contextFacade) {
        this.contextFacade = contextFacade;
    }

    public TreeNode getContextRoot() {
        return contextRoot;
    }

    public void setContextRoot(TreeNode contextRoot) {
        this.contextRoot = contextRoot;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        populateContextTree();
    }

    private void populateContextTree() {
        buildContextTree(new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null), contextFacade.findRootContexts());
    }

    private void buildContextTree(TreeNode parentNode, List<Context> children) {
        for (Context currentContextNode : children) {
            TreeNode tempNode = new DefaultTreeNode(currentContextNode, parentNode);
            buildContextTree(tempNode, currentContextNode.getChildren());
        }
        contextRoot = parentNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the bean to view scope or session scope?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try verifying if `selectedNode` is null by logging?  Perhaps it is getting set but the `update` attribute of your `<p:commandButton>` is not set correctly.  Remember that by default the `<h:form>` will prepend its id to child elements.

Also verify that there are no validation errors being thrown by other elements in the `<h:form>`

Further still I do not believe that a Primefaces tree component will work correctly when backed by a `@RequestScoped` managed bean.  Try changing the managed bean to `@ViewScoped` so that the lifecycle of the managed bean will span across individual requests.

Comment: I had the Tree component in a JSF template client with the form in the template.  Moving the form into the client page worked.  I was able to keep the backing bean RequestScoped.  Should one always have form components in the template client?

Comment: @Laurence, Yes, you will find that typically each client page should have at least one form.  Further you may run into some Primefaces bugs where you need more than one form.  One example is if you have multiple dialog components on a single page, it is best to put the contents of each dialog in a seperate form.

Answer (score 0):

I had the Tree component in a JSF template client with the form in the template. Moving the form into the client page worked. I was able to keep the backing bean RequestScoped.

Comment: So, you was basically nesting forms?

Comment: I had a form in the template, but not the template client.  I thought the form would be exposed to the client page, but apparently not.